# jdbc mysql driver not found after deploying

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I have developed a REST application using jersey where to connect to database(mysql) I use jdbc connection. Following is the configuration.

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME";

static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "********";

public List<Item> getAll() {
        List<Item> results = new ArrayList<>();

try (Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,
                USER, PASS);
                Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM items");) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("ID"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("FormerCode"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("NewCode"));
                results.add(new Item(rs.getInt("ID"), rs
                        .getString("FormerCode"), rs.getString("NewCode")));

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return results;

    }
```

All things works when I deploy via Eclipse. But when I create the war file and deploy it manually on tomcat server it gets the exception saying there is no suitable driver.

```
No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME
```

I have included the mysql-connector jar files in both WEB-INF/lib folder and TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder. But I am still getting this error. Server is running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Paths where jar is added.

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib 
usr/share/tomcat7/lib
```

What seems to be the problem hence I have added the jar files to necessary locations??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have included the code.

Comment: Ok, you have added the code, but it's unclear what are you asking. Do you want to know why the driver is not loaded or you have created a code that doesn't work? And this is *not*  MCVE of the web application.

Comment: I am asking although I have added the jar file to the necessary location why does it give the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was when using a DriverManager interface to create a JDBC Connection, always create an instance of your JDBC driver first in order to load it into your Classloader.

```
try {
    // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
    // broken Java implementations

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle the error
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes java class failed to pick driver's(`mysql java connector jar file`) path from lib folder. To remove this issue you can extract connector jar in following directory of your project.

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

OR

You may also compile the java file with classpath reference of `mysql_java_connector.jar`.

Comment: There is no folder called classes inside WEB-INF. Do I need to create this folder?